# EC2 permission denied(public key)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect parse server EC2 instance. But in ubuntu terminal after pasting ssh -i "instame.pem" admin@ec2.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com, error is coming as permission denied(public key). I have checked every thing and it is fine. As the instance plat form is Debian then the user name is admin. Despite of writing the expected command why I am getting the error?

Comment: What's the AMI you're using?

Answer (score 1):

"Permission denied (publickey)" and "Authentication failed, permission denied" errors occur if:

- You're trying to connect using the wrong user name for your AMI.
- The file permissions within the operating system are incorrect on the
  instance.
- The incorrect SSH public key (.pub) file is in the authorized_keys file.

Double check these before attempting another connection.